# Find inverse of exponential function

Tags: inverse

Do you know how I could compute the inverse function of the following exponential sentence?

$$y=\dfrac{e^x}{1+2e^x}$$

Comment: Can you solve for $x$ in terms of $y$?

Comment: Is it at all possible that you wanted $e^x$ rather than $e^2$ in the numerator?  (If so, then my answer below would have to get changed.)

Comment: this is my result $F^-1(x)=ln((x/1-2x))$

Comment: Michael you're right, what I want is $e^x$ rather than $e^2$constant.

Comment: For the amended question, the answer is correct.

Comment: OK, I've added to my answer in view of the amended question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\text{exponentiate} \longrightarrow \text{multiply by 2}\longrightarrow\text{add 1} \longrightarrow \text{reciprocal}\longrightarrow\text{multiply by }e^2
$$

**What gets done last gets undone first.**

So the inverse is:
$$
\text{Divide by }e^2\longrightarrow\text{reciprocal} \longrightarrow\text{subtract 1} \longrightarrow \text{divide by 2}\longrightarrow\text{take logarithm}
$$

I.e. if $y = \dfrac{e^2}{1+2e^x}$ then $x = \log_e\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{y/e^2} - 1}{2}\right)$.  (Then simplify.)

**LATER EDIT:**

Since you've now said you wanted $e^x$ in the numerator, here's that:
$$
y=\frac{e^x}{1+2e^x} = \frac{1}{e^{-x}+2}
$$
$$
\text{multiply by }-1 \longrightarrow \text{exponentiate} \longrightarrow \text{add 2} \longrightarrow\text{reciprocal}
$$

So the inverse is:
$$
\text{reciprocal} \longrightarrow\text{subtract 2}\longrightarrow\text{take logarithm} \longrightarrow\text{multiply by }-1
$$

(Two of the steps are their own inverses.) So
$$
x = -\log_e\left(\frac1y-2\right)
$$
(Then simplify.)

Comment: The answer is correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get how you go from $\frac{e^x}{1+2e^x}$ to $\frac{1}{e^{-x}+2}$

Comment: @MphLee : $\dfrac{e^x}{1+2e^x}$ $=\dfrac{e^x}{1+2e^x}\cdot\dfrac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}}$.  When you multiply the numerators you get $e^x\cdot e^{-x}=1$.  When you multiply the denominators you get $(1+2e^x)(e^{-x})$ $=(e^{-x}) + (2e^x e^{-x})$.  And $2e^x e^{-x}=2\cdot1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\dfrac{e^2}{1+2e^x}$$
$$1+2e^x=e^2/y$$
$$2e^x=e^2/y-1$$
$$e^x=\frac{e^2/y-1}{2}$$
$$x=\ln{\frac{e^2/y-1}{2}}$$